# How can I find the asker's profile for a migrated question when they have not associated their accounts on the new site?

Tags: support, users, linked-accounts, migrated-questions

In this case, the following question was migrated from SO to Server Fault: https://serverfault.com/questions/258130/how-to-redirect-bounce-email-to-one-email-address

The asker has never been to Server Fault before. I can't click on their profile, and I can't look them up on SO—there are too many users named Kai and and I have no idea what the user ID is.

Question asker cannot be determined on migrated questions until the asker signs in.

Comment: It's not a bug to not have a profile for a user that doesn't exist

Comment: So the point is that you want to look at the user's SO profile, but can't because you only have the name to go by, not the unique user id?  Seems like this should be a feature-request of some kind.

Comment: OP of that question has only one post on SO.  Not much to see there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Step One: Accumulate 10k reputation on Stack Overflow.
- Step Two: Click on the link below from the question page on Server Fault:

  > ### migrated from [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616629/how-to-redirect-bounce-email-to-one-email-address?noredirect=1) Apr 11 at 5:12
  >
  > This question came from our site for professional and enthusiast
  >   programmers.
- Step Three: Harvest the user from the deleted question (it's [that Kai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701523/kai)).

Comment: You only need 10k for when the question is ultimately deleted. For the first 30 days (I think) the question still exists on the original site and following the link back will show you the page from where you can get to the user profile.

Answer (score 1):

If user hasn't account on site question was migrated to, you just can't find "his profile"

It's not a bug.